# Merged "Program Files" and "Program Files (x86)" into single folder. Can I undo it?

Tags: windows-7

I'm using Windows 7 64 bit, and tried to tidy up my folders. I saw there were 2 program files folders, so I merged `Program Files` and `Program Files (x86)` together by mistake.

It's been days now so I cannot undo my actions. Would moving the folders back to as they were before fix everything?

Comment: What version of windows are you using? What was the reason behind moving the program files?

Comment: So I use Windows 7 64bit, And I tried to tidy up my folders. I saw there were 2 program files folders so I merged them to make it one single folder.

Comment: Do all your programs (Office - Word, Excel, power point, VLC, Windows media player etc.,) work properly? Or do you get errors like shortcut link is not found?

Comment: Do you remember which you merged into which, and if you then chose to replace or keep files that were already in the target folder? (If applicable.)

Answer (score 1):

Most programs will work again if you move them back, but office and other microsoft tools are likely not going to work, as they have folders in both folders. You need to uninstall those, then remove the folder manually, and then reinstall the program for it to work.